# is it possible to recreate this menu in CSS?

Tags: html, css

[image: Menu]

Roll over the text and the blue block below moves along the blue line. If I do it via position relative and set the blue block to top 20px, it also moves the text down.

Is there a way I can do this purely in CSS, or should I use a background image with the top half set as a transparent gif and the bottom blue?

The code I've tried so far is:

```
#menu ul {
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:10px;
    text-align:center;
}
#menu ul li {
    display:block;
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
    margin-right: 40px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    height: 39px;
}
#menu ul li a {
    display:block;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    color:#FFF;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
#menu ul li a:hover {
    color:#fff;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
}
#menu ul li a.active,
#menu ul li a.active:hover {
    color:#fff;
    background-color: #0488C5;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

I am still learning so excuse any mistakes!

Comment: yes it's possible .............

Comment: Yes, you can easily create this purely in HTML and CSS. `:hover` will help you.

Comment: First, be more specific. What is your desired target platform? What have you tried? How does your markup and css look like? Nobody wants to do someone else's job.

Comment: see my answer and let me know if iam lagging some where

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Click here for a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/spacebeers/wu33u/1/).

```
​<ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="active">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
</ul>

ul {
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 3px solid blue;
    overflow: hidden;
}

li {
    float: left;  
    margin: 0 20px 0 20px;                
}

li a {
    border-bottom: 20px solid #fff;
    display: block;
}

li a:hover, .active {
    border-bottom: 20px solid blue;
}
```

​You can then use the hover state for another class called something like "active" that you can apply when on that page.

You should be able to tweak this example to suit your needs.

You don't need any images. CSS is more than capable of doing this for you.

Comment: Thank you! It was this line I needed: border-bottom: 20px solid blue;

Comment: No worries. You can fake the border not being there by giving it the same colour as the background. Easier than faffing around with margins and padding. Glad to have helped.

Answer (score 1):

....................................

***[Live demo](http://tinkerbin.com/jDW8s6q6)***

Hi now this is possible used to `after in css`

as a simple example is this

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Css**

```
   ul{
list-style:none;
  border-bottom:solid 10px blue;
}
li{
display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  background:red; 
}
li a{
text-decoration:none;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  position:relative;
  padding-left:10px;
  padding-right:10px;
  padding-bottom:10px;
}

li:hover a:after{
content:'';
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  height:10px;
  background:blue;
}
```

***[LIve demo](http://tinkerbin.com/jDW8s6q6)***

Answer (score 0):

Place three anchors in an unordered list and have them displayed in-line by setting the list display to none an floating the list items. Further add an empty span to each anchor which you can style with the :hover pseudo selector.

Learn CSS, its fun!